# How to add a FormGroup to a FormArray without triggering form change event

Tags: angular

I initialise a form with any empty array in `definitionProperties` how can I update `FormGroup`? I need to do so without triggering a change event otherwise it causes an infinite loop in the `valueChanges` observable.

```
this.gridProcessorForm = this.fb.group({
    propertiesSide: new FormControl(),
    objectNamesSide: new FormControl(),
    definitionProperties: this.fb.array([])
});
```

This causes the infinite loop:

```
this.gridProcessorForm.valueChanges.subscribe(val => {
    let propertyGroups: FormGroup[] = [];
    for (let property of this.objectDefinition.properties) {
      let group = this.createPropertyFormGroup(property);
      (this.gridProcessorForm.get('definitionProperties') as FormArray).push(group); // triggers change event so infinite loop
    }
});
```

When using setValue with `{ emitEvent: false }` to overwrite the FormArray it gets an error.

```
this.gridProcessorForm.valueChanges.subscribe(val => {
  if (this.gridSideSelection = 'top') {        
    let propertyGroups: FormGroup[] = [];
    for (let property of this.objectDefinition.properties) {
      let group = this.createPropertyFormGroup(property);
      propertyGroups.push(group);
    }

    (this.gridProcessorForm.get('definitionProperties') as FormArray).setValue(propertyGroups, { emitEvent: false });
  }
});
```

I get this error:

```
There are no form controls registered with this array yet.
```

It seems it requires the form builder to initialise with a group in the FormArray? But I want to initialise the form with everything empty.

Comment: what is `propertyGroups`?

Comment: an array of FormGroups

Answer (score 4):

There's an issue in angular's repo. Please refer this comment https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/23336#issuecomment-543209703

Basically, you need to do it like this:

```js
const addedControl = new FormControl();
this.controlArray.controls.push(addedControl);
this.controlArray['_registerControl'](addedControl);
```

### UPDATE 05.2021

This was fixed in Angular v12 https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/20439#issuecomment-779988084

Answer (score 1):

I hope this will help as this is my running code.

```
    let containersArray = <FormArray>this.formName.controls['containers'];
    containersArray.push(this.addContainerInitialize(container));


addContainerInitialize(value) {

    return this.fb.group({
        containerNumber: [value.containerNumber],
        conType: [value.conType, Validators.required],
        quantity: [value.noOfContainers, Validators.required],
        weight: [value.grossWeight, Validators.required]
    });
}
```

Comment: this triggers change event, need this: { emitEvent: false }

Comment: I think the only option is to overwrite the FormArray there is no function on the FormArray to add without triggering the change event

Answer (score 0):

not my answer - answer given by https://github.com/MrCroft

```
this.frm.valueChanges
.pipe(
  filter(_ => !this.pauseForm)
)
.subscribe(
  (v) => {
    // DO STUFF
  }
);
```

Then, whenever I need to use setControl/addControl, I first do this.pauseForm = true; and after set/addControll I do this.pauseForm = false;

this answer was present on this thread - https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/20439 and it works.